# Tool to transform webmail to imap

Tags: imap

I have a problem. I work for a company that only provides webmail for users (admins tell it is for security blabla, i have no influence on that) Since I receive a lot of mails working with webmail is very uncomfortable. Therefore I would like to know if any of you is aware of a kind of gateway that would allow me to use an imap client (mutt in my case) to connect to that webinterface. This kind of gateway certainly exists. My company uses outlook.

I would be very happy if you could point me to a tool playing that kind of gateway.

Answer (score 1):

Haven't used it myself, but this is supposed to work with Outlook Web Access on Ubuntu:
[DavMail POP/IMAP/SMTP/Caldav/Carddav/LDAP Exchange Gateway](http://davmail.sourceforge.net/)